# Call open_session_cb to create a new session for pos in odoo 8.0

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-8

Im trying to create a new session in pos in odoo 8.0 by an api service but i have an error with the arguments

Im using php to conect with odoo services

```php
    $models->execute_kw(
        $db,
       $uid,
       $password,
       'pos.session.opening',
       'open_session_cb',
       array(),
       array()
    );
```

tha gives to me the next error :
TypeError: open_session_cb() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

Comment: I think we need to see more code... unless someone else is familiar with odoo. Do you call the `open_session_cb` function directly anywhere in your code?

Comment: Hi @Victor and welcome to SO :-) Please consider adding `odoo` in your tag list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Try something like:

```
$models->execute_kw(
   $db,
   $uid,
   $password,
   'pos.session.opening',
   'open_session_cb',
   array(array($pos_session_id)),
   array()
);
```

Long answer: The function `open_session_cb` is defined at `<path_to_v8>/addons/point_of_sale/wizard/pos_session_opening.py` line 41 as follows:

```
41 def open_session_cb(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
       ...
44     wizard = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
```

One level up in the call stack it is `<path_to_v8>/openerp/service/model.py` line 164 (cited below)

```
160 def execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw):
161     object = openerp.registry(cr.dbname).get(obj)
162     if object is None:
163         raise except_orm('Object Error', "Object %s doesn't exist" % obj)
164     return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
```

So, when calling `open_session_cb`, arguments `self, cr`, and `uid` are supplied by the calling function but you need to supply the variable `ids` which is expected to be an array containing the integer corresponding to the field `id` from the model `pos.session.opening`
on the record for the session you want to open.

Comment: It works but I think that I got  the wrong idea what I really want to do was to create a new pos session and this method is based on an existing pos session